# Python, random, комбинации

Tags: python, случайные-числа

У меня есть код:

```
from random import choice

комбинация = ['w', 4, 5, 2, 'a', 8, 3, 9, 7, 6, 'g', 'r', 1, 'y']

my_ticket = []

def random():
    return choice(комбинация)
    
def перебор():
    print("Выигрышная комбинация:")
    for i in range(4):
        print(random())
    


перебор()
```

подскажите пожалуйста, как данные из метода перебор() перенести в список my_ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Комментарии, объясняющие изменения, смотри в тексте (русские имена я также заменил на английские)

```
from random import choice

combination = ['w', 4, 5, 2, 'a', 8, 3, 9, 7, 6, 'g', 'r', 1, 'y']

my_ticket = []


def random():
    return choice(combination)


def perebor():
    print("Выигрышная комбинация:")
    # i не использовался - заменён согласно правилам хорошего стиля
    for _ in range(4):
        # Просто добавляем к списку, так как список в области видимости по правилам языка
        my_ticket.append(random())
        # Распечатываем последний (добавленный) элемент списка
        print(my_ticket[-1])

perebor()
```

Comment: Спасибо за такое четкое объяснение, насчет i это для меня интересный факт, буду учитывать далее в своих программах,но не могли бы помочь мне еще, у меня дальше есть задача создать цикл который будет перебирать комбинации, и когда цикл найдет нужную комбинацию (как в my_ticket) то он должен остановиться, и написать сколько попыток потребовалось что-бы найти нужную комбинацию, если не трудно пожалуйста помогите

Comment: Давайте действовать по правилам сайта + чтобы и вам польза была. 1) Этот вопрос принимайте, если вопросов нет, так как  правило сайта - не смешивать разные  вопросы в одном запросе. 2) Начните делать сами, так как алгоритм вы примерно уже понимате, как я думаю (если нет - продумайте и напишите себе на бумажке, например).  Если возникнет сложность - открывайте новый запрос с тем, что у вас получилось (с кодом) и с вопросом по конкретной проблеме. Но задача не сложная, как минимум, большая часть получится.

Comment: хорошо, я создам новый вопрос, как не старался не получается выполнить задачу, спасибо за совет, в первые вижу такого вежливого человека на форуме

Comment: Вы просто тут недолго:-) Это очень вежливый форум.